# Range adding and multiplication in Excel

Tags: excel

At the moment I have 2 sheets, Sheet1 has some values and Sheet2 has some other values.  Then I have Sheet 3 where I wish to do some calculations in.

To give you an idea, at the moment I am doing the following:-

```
=((Sheet1!B2*Sheet2!B15)+(Sheet1!C2*Sheet2!C15)+(Sheet1!D2*Sheet2!D15)),
```

which is working correctly.

However, I have 36 cells I need to do the same exact thing.  So I was wondering if there was some formula or range in Excel which can make my life easier.

Any ideas which might help me pls?

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!$B$2:$AK$2,Sheet2!$B$15:$AK$15)
```